# Adapter list item update issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm working on a screen where I have to display twice the same collection of items. I'm using two `RecyclerView`'s each with a different instance of the same `Adapter`

Besides the two `RecyclerViews` in the screen I have a `continue` button to go to the next screen.

I want to put some constraints on the button so that the user will not be able to proceed to the next screen if he doesn't select an item from each `RecyclerView`

The following method is called when the user taps on an item.

```
fun setSelection(item: Item) {
    list.forEach {
        it.isSelected = false
        if (it.id == item.id) it.isSelected = true
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

And to verify if the list has at least one selected item I use this:

```
fun isAnySelected(): Boolean {
    return list.any { item -> item.isSelected }
}
```

In the button's `clickListener` I added this verification:

```
if ((first_recycler.adapter as CustomAdapter).isAnySelected() &&
   (second_recycler.adapter as CustomAdapter).isAnySelected()) 
{ //go to next screen } 
else{
// select an item before continue }
```

My problem is that if I select an item only from one `RecyclerView`, when I tap on the `continue` button both of them will return `true`.

Why does `(second_recycler.adapter as CustomAdapter).isAnySelected()` returns `true` if only

```
(first_massage_display.mdl_recycler.adapter as MassageAdapter).setSelection(item)
```

Is called?

Comment: Just a tip. Your logic inside `forEach` can be simplified to `it.isSelected = it.id == item.id`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the lists in each adapter are referencing the same list item instances. This could be because you passed the same list to both adapters, or simply that you have not created distinct list item instances in each list. If two lists reference the same list items, than changing a list item in one list also changes it in the other.

I recommend making `Item` a data class so you can easily make copies. Then create a copy of the list where every member of the list is also copied, and pass that to the second Adapter. You can use `map()` to do both steps of copying the list and the items within it all at once:

```
val secondList = firstList.map(Item::copy)
```

Comment: You are right. I'm passing the same list to both adapters. But I tried your solution and I can't pass the `secondList` val in the Adapter. Can you provide a more explicit way to copy the list?